# Old questions that clearly asks to find a tool was this not a close reason before?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, old-questions

While working review queue I stumbled upon old question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688/best-tool-for-auto-generating-sql-change-scripts-for-sql-server

The question clearly asks to find a tool which is a valid close reason but there are not even a single close vote (until I did)

Was the following close reason implemented sometime after the question been asked? And is it wrong to close or migrate this question or any other old questions that fall into this or any other **currently valid** close reasons?

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite
>   off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to
>   attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem
>   and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Migrate no (can't be migrated due to the age), but definitely vote to close if you believe the close reason applies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Was the following close reason implemented sometime after the question been asked?

Yes.  Questions like that have been considered inappropriate for a number of years.  The exact wording of the close reason you refer to is newer still, but that question is actually old enough to predate *both* the specific wording, and the underlying concept that preceeded it.

> And is it wrong to close or migrate this question or any other old questions that fall into this or any other currently valid close reasons?

No.  If a question meets any of the *current* closure criteria then vote to close it, regardless of its age.

Comment: Why can't older questions be migrated?

Comment: @DanDascalescu Such questions tend to not fare well on the migrated site; they often have some votes/links to it and removing it causes problems in those regards, etc.

Comment: @Servy: I came across a old upvoted question on tag with very less active user base. I can cast close vote but it will be of no use; it will age away anyway. Is there a way to gather a support for old questions as we have for new questions through SOCVR?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, yes.  This wasn't as big of a deal back in the beginning, when SO was still learning what being SO meant.  So you have some (in cases, very good) questions that are not consistent with the current philosophy.

If they're not good-today questions, Vote to Close is appropriate.  Important lists might be protected, but in most cases they're really not that useful.